# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' caused by NoClassDefFoundError caused by ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

I have 2 different projects as below

```
Root Project
    |
    |--commons(Library)
    |     |--Gender.kt(Enum)
    |
    |--user-manager(uses commons library)
    |     |--UserProfile.kt (JPA @Entity which uses Gender as a field)
```

If I move the Gender.kt in user-manager project, everything works fine. The moment I move it to commons library, I get the following error while running the Spring Boot application

```
17:21:17: Executing task 'bootRun'...

> Task :common:compileKotlin
> Task :common:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :common:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :common:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :common:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Task :common:jar SKIPPED
> Task :user-manager:compileKotlin
> Task :user-manager:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :user-manager:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :user-manager:classes UP-TO-DATE

> Task :user-manager:bootRun

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::             (v2.2.0.M1)

2019-03-18 17:21:26.049  INFO 18244 --- [           main] c.s.u.UserServiceApplicationKt           : Starting UserServiceApplicationKt on LPTP-BLR-Nayan with PID 18244 (E:\Repos\HC7\user-manager\build\classes\kotlin\main started by nayan.kurude in E:\Repos\HC7\user-manager)
2019-03-18 17:21:26.056  INFO 18244 --- [           main] c.s.u.UserServiceApplicationKt           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-03-18 17:21:28.540  INFO 18244 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-03-18 17:21:28.806  INFO 18244 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 239ms. Found 3 repository interfaces.
2019-03-18 17:21:29.810  INFO 18244 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1be4cc54] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-03-18 17:21:31.356  INFO 18244 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-03-18 17:21:31.407  INFO 18244 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-03-18 17:21:31.408  INFO 18244 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16]
2019-03-18 17:21:31.432  INFO 18244 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Users\nayan.kurude\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\nayan.kurude\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\nayan.kurude\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Gradle\bin;;.]
2019-03-18 17:21:31.635  INFO 18244 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-03-18 17:21:31.636  INFO 18244 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5466 ms
2019-03-18 17:21:32.681  INFO 18244 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-03-18 17:21:34.375  INFO 18244 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-03-18 17:21:34.608  INFO 18244 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-03-18 17:21:34.952  INFO 18244 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.0.Final}
2019-03-18 17:21:34.957  INFO 18244 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-03-18 17:21:35.408  INFO 18244 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2019-03-18 17:21:35.672  INFO 18244 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
2019-03-18 17:21:36.074  WARN 18244 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/simbalarry/common/enums/Gender
2019-03-18 17:21:36.075  INFO 18244 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-03-18 17:21:36.082  INFO 18244 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2019-03-18 17:21:36.088  INFO 18244 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-03-18 17:21:36.113  INFO 18244 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-03-18 17:21:36.125 ERROR 18244 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/simbalarry/common/enums/Gender
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M1.jar:2.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:785) [spring-boot-2.2.0.M1.jar:2.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:407) [spring-boot-2.2.0.M1.jar:2.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot-2.2.0.M1.jar:2.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1278) [spring-boot-2.2.0.M1.jar:2.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1266) [spring-boot-2.2.0.M1.jar:2.2.0.M1]
    at com.simbalarry.usermanager.UserServiceApplicationKt.main(UserServiceApplication.kt:13) [main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/simbalarry/common/enums/Gender
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXClass.getDeclaredMethodProperties(JavaXClass.java:95) ~[hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXClass.getDeclaredProperties(JavaXClass.java:112) ~[hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXClass.getDeclaredProperties(JavaXClass.java:104) ~[hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:252) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:785) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:250) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:274) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:903) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:934) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.simbalarry.common.enums.Gender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    ... 37 common frames omitted


> Task :user-manager:bootRun FAILED
w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build\kotlin\sessions

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

As mentioned above I have a Gender.kt file which is in commons library and I am using it in JPA Entity class in user-manager module. The project compiles fine, but while running, it throws the exception as above.

Could anyone please help me with this? 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If `commons(Library)` is an artifact used by the `Root Project` check if the `Root Project` scans the packages from the `commons(Library)` at start up

Comment: I added code below in UserServiceApplicaton.kt Still no luck

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages=["com.simbalarry.common", "com.simbalarry.usermanager"])
class UserServiceApplication



fun main(args: Array<String>) {
 runApplication<UserServiceApplication>(*args)
}